# Vuetify appbar double scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am currently trying to develop an app with vuetify. However i can not get the scroll threshold appbar to work correctly. If I get the content placed correctly then the shrink on scroll doesn't work correctly, and vice-versa. I managed to get the content and scroll bar positioned in relation to each other but now there is a large amount of blankspace under the footer and the app is using the vuetify scroll bar and not the browser scroll bar.

[image: Vuetify app screenshot]

Here is my App.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-app>

  <v-app-bar 
      app
      style="position:fixed"
      absolute
      color="#43a047"
      dark
      shrink-on-scroll
      prominent
      src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random"
      fade-img-on-scroll
      scroll-target="#scrolling-techniques-5"
      scroll-threshold="500"
    >
    <template v-slot:img="{ props }">
        <v-img
          v-bind="props"
          gradient="to top right, rgba(55,236,186,.7), rgba(25,32,72,.7)"
        ></v-img>
      </template>
    <!-- -->
  </v-app-bar>
  <v-sheet
      id="scrolling-techniques-5"
      class="overflow-y-auto"
      max-height="600"
    >
      <v-container  fluid style="height: 1500px;">
        <v-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    
      </v-main>
    </v-container>
    
  </v-sheet>
    
  <!-- Sizes your content based upon application components -->
  <v-footer
    color="primary lighten-1"
    padless
  >
    <v-row
      justify="center"
      no-gutters
    >
      <v-btn
        v-for="link in links"
        :key="link"
        color="white"
        text
        rounded
        class="my-2"
      >
        {{ link }}
      </v-btn>
      <v-col
        class="primary lighten-2 py-4 text-center white--text"
        cols="12"
      >
        {{ new Date().getFullYear() }} — <strong>Vuetify</strong>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-footer>

  
</v-app>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      links: [
        'Home',
        'About Us',
        'Team',
        'Services',
        'Blog',
        'Contact Us',
      ],
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height `height: 1500px` on the `v-container`

```
 <v-sheet
      id="scrolling-techniques-5"
      class="overflow-y-auto"
      max-height="600"
    >
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    
      </v-main>
    </v-container>
    
  </v-sheet>
```